# Setting innerHTML increases HTML nodecount

Tags: javascript, html

### Explain the problem

So i noticed that on using `someElement.innerHTML` the DOM Nodes count increases.

[image]

I guess that the reference is killed but the memory is still allocated until the garbage collector deletes the object.

---

Example(HTML):

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="startTimer()">
        <div id="timeContainer">Time Goes Here</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Example(JavaScript):

```
 var timer;
 var body;
 var oldTime = "";
 var timeContainer;


 function startTimer(){
    timeContainer = document.getElementById("timeContainer");
    timer = setInterval(getTime, 10);
 }

function getTime(){
    var d = new Date();
    var timeString = d.getUTCHours() +":"+ d.getUTCMinutes(); +":"+ d.getUTCSeconds();

    if(timeString != oldTime){
        oldTime = timeString;
        timeContainer.innerHTML = timeString;
    }
}
```

### What i tried so far

- I tried to use `someElement.textContent`.
- I deleted the whoe ParentElement everytime it refreshes the timer and created a new one

### Question

How can i avoid to increase the node count even once when im just refreshing content and why does it need an extra Node anyways?

Comment: Please don't link to pictures if they are part of your question. Include the picture in the question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That looks ways better, thanks! i was wondering why it wouldnt preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess that the reference is killed but the memory is still allocated
>   until the garbage collector deletes the object.

Correct.

> How can i avoid to increase the node count even once when im just
>   refreshing content?

You can't, nor should you worry about it. This is the browser's domain, it does what it wants to do when it comes to garbage collection (and different browsers might do it differently).

> I deleted the whole ParentElement everytime it refreshes the timer and
>   created a new one

Just because you deleted it (made it inaccessible), doesn't mean it was garbage collected instantly.

Comment: I would agree completely. You can't performance tune this - let the browser do its thing.

Comment: So lets say i use  100 x `innerHTML` every ms and this dom count quickly raises over 5000 i should not be worried? And why does it even need another DOM node anyways?

Comment: @notanumber - you should absolutely be worried and you should probably not be doing what you're doing in that case - stop modifying the DOM so heavily and frequently. The bottom line is, it's the browser's decision on how to handle references out of scope and when to garbage collect them and you can't make it do anything it doesn't want to do.

Comment: @notanumber *why does it even need another DOM node anyways* - good question, to which, I'm sure, there is a good answer, I don't know.

Comment: @Adam yeah it is really worst case scenario (just for imagine the problem on a bigger scale) . But thanks anyways!

Comment: `.innerHTML` and `.textContent` need to create new nodes (ELEMENT nodes in the case of `.innerHTML` and TEXT nodes in the case of `.textContnet`) most likely for the same reason string manipulations return new strings (immutability).

Comment: Also, never manipulate the DOM in a loop. Instead, build up a string and inject that into the DOM in one `.innerHTML` operation.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - Of course, a text node is still a node, I forgot that. Nice one.

Answer (score 2):

**This is natural and expected.**

Browsers garbage collection run asynchronously. As soon as your actual DOM detached the nodes, it's not guaranteed that they are free from heap. They'll stay there until the next garbage collection trigger.

As [told in dev tools # Fix Memory Problems](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/), don't worry about it and leave it to garbage collection process.

Note that, leave it to GC as long as it is not hurting your applications performance. If it is really pushing you in to browser slow&hang mess, you should really start profilling it and fix it. That could be a potential memory leak.

> A DOM node can only be garbage collected when there are no references to it from either the page's DOM tree or JavaScript code. A node is said to be "detached" when it's removed from the DOM tree but some JavaScript still references it. Detached DOM nodes are a common cause of memory leaks. This section teaches you how to use DevTools' heap profilers to identify detached nodes.

And fix is given in the same article using Chrome Dev tools. In short, take snapshots of you heap and start looking at detached nodes.

[image]

Nodes highlighted yellow have direct references to them from the JavaScript code. Nodes highlighted red do not have direct references. They are only alive because they are part of the yellow node's tree. In general, you want to focus on the yellow nodes. Fix your code so that the yellow node isn't alive for longer than it needs to be, and you also get rid of the red nodes that are part of the yellow node's tree.

[Read more ..](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/)

Comment: Great advice on how to view these and steps to release them.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Click on the link - Step by step process given with screenshots.

Comment: Is garbage collection asynchronous, or do you just mean that's its run all the time? Java's GC is synchronous, I couldn't find any information, but I assumed JS GC is synchronous, too.

Comment: It's asynchronous. The browser does this via its OS programming, not via the JavaScript engine.