# My game has a performance leak and I cant find it

Tags: javascript

I made a post regarding this issue but realized it wasn't very well said, so I deleted it and I'm making this post a bit more informative. So I made this game a while back, its a game where one plays as a color and collects other color balls and gets points. You can play it below with my working code snippet. After a while, like say 30 or 45 seconds, the game lags out a lot and doesn't play very well. I've checked everywhere but can't seem to find any place where I repeat things every frame which could slow down things. Is there any way I can find where the performance issue is?

Here is the snippet:

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById("can").getContext("2d");
let can = document.getElementById("can");
let width = can.width;
let height = can.height;
let disp = document.getElementById("dis");


ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.rect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
ctx.fill();
ctx.font = "30px ComicSans";
let colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];



let Player = function(){
  this.x = 250;
  this.y = 400;
  this.colornum = 0;
  this.xspeed = 10;
  this.yspeed = 10;
  this.pressRight = false;
  this.pressLeft = false;
  this.pressUp = false;
  this.pressDown = false;
  this.radius = 30;
  this.num = 0;


  this.draw = function(){

    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[this.colornum];
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    //Number Style
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
    ctx.fillText(this.num, this.x - 15, this.y + 10);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();

  }

  this.updatePosition = function(){
    if(this.pressRight){
      if(this.x + this.radius < can.width){
        this.x += this.xspeed;
      }
    }else if(this.pressLeft){
      if(this.x - this.radius > 0){
        this.x -= this.xspeed;
      }
    }else if(this.pressUp){
      if(this.y - this.radius > 0){
        this.y -= this.yspeed;
      }
    }else if(this.pressDown){
      if(this.y + this.radius < can.height){
        this.y += this.yspeed;
      }
    }
  }

  this.update = function(){
    this.updatePosition();
    this.draw();
  }

}

let Entity = function(){
  this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
  this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
  this.colornum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  this.xspeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
  this.yspeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);

  this.collide = function(){
    if(this.x > can.width || this.x < 0){
      this.xspeed = -this.xspeed;
    }
    if(this.y > can.height || this.y < 0){
      this.yspeed = -this.yspeed;
    }
  }

  this.updatePosition = function(){
    this.collide();
    this.x += this.xspeed;
    this.y += this.yspeed;
  }

  this.draw = function(){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 20, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[this.colornum];
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

  }

  this.update = function(){
    this.updatePosition();
    this.draw();
  }
}

let player1 = new Player();

let enemylist = {};

for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++){
  let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  enemylist[id] = new Entity();
}

function CollideDetect(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  if(Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1)) < (player1.radius + 20)){
    return true;
  }else
  return false;
}

function update(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "White";
  ctx.rect(0,0,800,600);
  ctx.fill();

  for(let key in enemylist){
    let collided = CollideDetect(enemylist[key].x, enemylist[key].y, player1.x, player1.y);
    if(collided && player1.colornum == enemylist[key].colornum){
      player1.radius += 5;
      player1.num += 1;
      delete enemylist[key];
    }else if(collided && player1.colornum != enemylist[key].colornum){
      if(player1.num <= 0 || player1.radius <5){
        delete enemylist[key];
      }else{
        player1.radius -= 5;
        player1.num -= 1;
        delete enemylist[key];
      }
    }
  }

  for(let key in enemylist){
    enemylist[key].update();
  }
  player1.update();

  if(Object.keys(enemylist).length == 0){
    disp.innerHTML = "Game Over";
  }else if(Object.keys(enemylist).length != 0){
    disp.innerHTML = "Start";
  }
}

let Restart = function(){
  if(Object.keys(enemylist).length == 0){
    player1.num = 0;
    player1.radius =30;
    for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++){
      let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      enemylist[id] = new Entity();
    }
  }

}



document.onkeydown = function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 68){
    player1.pressRight = true;
  }else if(event.keyCode == 65){
    player1.pressLeft = true;
  }else if(event.keyCode == 83){
    player1.pressDown = true;
  }else if(event.keyCode == 87){
    player1.pressUp = true;
  }else if(event.keyCode == 71){
    player1.colornum = 0;
  }else if(event.keyCode == 72){
    player1.colornum = 1;
  }else if(event.keyCode == 74){
    player1.colornum = 2;
  }
}

document.onkeyup = function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 68){
    player1.pressRight = false;
  }else if(event.keyCode == 65){
    player1.pressLeft = false;
  }else if(event.keyCode == 83){
    player1.pressDown = false;
  }else if(event.keyCode == 87){
    player1.pressUp = false;
  }else if(event.keyCode == 87){

  }
}

let gameloop = function(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);
  update();
}

gameloop();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Collision Game</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Collision Game</h1>

    <button onclick="Restart()">Restart </button>

    <canvas id="can" height="600" width="800" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
    <p id="dis">Start</p>

    <script src="game.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: WASD to move and HJK to change color

Comment: Once done collecting color you can restart the game, after about 3 restarts, the lag becomes prominent

Comment: Can't say that I'm noticing any lag... are you sure you're not misinterpreting the fact that you can only move in one direction at a time as lag when you press more than one button at a time, so it only "responds" to the new button after you release the old one?  Thats the only thing that seems "laggy" to me, but it's just an implementation detail

Comment: @JamesThorpe After about 4 restarts, I get massive amounts of lag and it becomes unplayable. And no, the keypresses are fine and don't seem laggy

Comment: Play it for a while (like only 3 minutes or maybe even less) and you find it becomes very slow.

Comment: I have heard that `delete xxx` doesn't work super well in some browsers. Also might want to run the `update()` before `requestAnimationFrame()`

Comment: Oh, hmmm, Let me try something else then. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Is there anything else I can use to replace delete with?

Comment: its a dumb but fun game, pretty nice

Comment: `enemylist.splice(key, 1)` This removes in place so no re-assignment is needed

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Ok I will take your suggestions and see if anything works.

Comment: You will also need to loop backwards instead of forwards when deleting.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn What do you mean?

Comment: so like `let key=enemylist.length;while(key--){ /* code */ enemylist.splice(key, 1) }` if you loop forward you might skip over items.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Hi, But I don't think splice will work in this case, as enemylist is an object and not an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174955/discussion-between-plzhelp-and-get-off-my-lawn).

Comment: I just realized that. I would convert it into an array. I don't think that an object is the best type for a group of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()`.

In a game they are basically useless since you are clearing the canvas and redrawing everything from scratch on every update. We don't need any of the saved information on the next frame anyways.

The [drawing state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save#Drawing_state) that gets saved onto a stack consists of:

- The current transformation matrix.
- The current clipping region.
- The current dash list.
- The current values of the following attributes:

  - strokeStyle
  - fillStyle
  - globalAlpha
  - lineWidth
  - lineCap
  - lineJoin
  - miterLimit
  - lineDashOffset
  - shadowOffsetX
  - shadowOffsetY
  - shadowBlur
  - shadowColor
  - globalCompositeOperation
  - font
  - textAlign
  - textBaseline
  - direction
  - imageSmoothingEnabled

None of these are that useful in a game that redraws from frame to frame, which makes calling `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` pointless. That doesn't mean you can't use `strokeStyle`, `fillStyle`, etc. it is just pointless to save that data.

Comment: This is the right answer for whomever will come on this thread. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with the code some, I found the issue.

### The issue

You are calling `disp.innerHTML` way too much. The garbage collector cannot keep up with the number of times that it is updating the dom.

So, if we take this section of code and move it out of the update loop and into its own `setInterval(..., 500)` the game plays and the dom can keep up.

Which make this:

```
if (Object.keys(enemylist).length == 0) {
  disp.innerHTML = "Game Over";
} else if (Object.keys(enemylist).length != 0) {
  disp.innerHTML = "Start";
}
```

Become this:

```
setInterval(() = > {
  if (Object.keys(enemylist).length == 0) {
    disp.innerHTML = "Game Over";
  } else if (Object.keys(enemylist).length != 0) {
    disp.innerHTML = "Start";
  }
}, 500)
```

### How I found this

When running a performance test in the chrome dev tools, I saw that there were over 800 nodes, but when looking at the elements there were only a few elements in the page. However, the `p` element was updating a lot. So we just slow down the rate at which it updates and we fix the problem, and now we keep below 100 nodes!

Comment: Wow, I'm so grateful for all your help. Thanks so much

Comment: Wait so updating elements on the dom counts as a "node"?

Comment: I guess so... I assume it rebuilds the node completely and puts the old node aside for garbage collection.

Comment: here is a SO question about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176399/setting-innerhtml-increases-html-nodecount

Comment: Hi, I removed that p element completely, but it still runs slowly after a while. And checking the performance, it said that there were still 400 - 416 nodes

Comment: Is there a way to do this without making so many nodes? Should I increase the timing for the set Interval?

Comment: Yeah, you could increase the timing. I tried with 1000 which was working.

Comment: Hi, I tried with a 1000 but still it takes more time, but again, it slows the game down. I also see that the nodes are a problem. At least we identified that. Is there a way I can keep this function which is essential and not use so many nodes

Comment: The node count keeps increasing ever so often. I think there is something else that is increasing it but I don't know what.

Comment: I feel like if we completely remove the `disp.innerHTML` and the interval it seems to work. If you remove them are you seeing the same thing?

Comment: I found something interesting. Even after removing disp.innerHTML, the game still slows down. I also checked the performance. And the nodes seem to be not increasing but wavering below 100, which is good I guess. But it still seems to slow down. I'm now thinking that nodes is not the problem here. But i did find the JSHeap increasing ever so often now.

Comment: Nevermind, Js heap also stays but wavers. It's not increasing, my bad.

Comment: I think I found it. I think it is one of 2 things. 1) in `Entity.draw()` you don't call `ctx.restore()` Might cause issues? 2) Removing all `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` calls runs pretty well for me. might as well remove them since you are clearing the canvas on every update. I don't think it is really needed

Comment: OMG! You fixed it, I LOVE YOU! YESSS Thanks soooo much. It's working smoothly, I've played for like 5 mins and no slows down. Let me put pack the inner.html and see if it's also smooth. THANKS. Can you put another answer with the ctx.restore so I can say that it's correct? Thanks A LOT man